# Problema al comparar una cadena almacenada en un archivo con otra cadena escrita por el usuario

Tags: c

La palabra se encuentra en el archivo pero no lo logro comparar, como podría solucionarlo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    FILE *archivo;
    char extraer_registros[100][100];
    int i = 0;
    archivo = fopen("ordenamiento.txt", "r+");
    char palabra[100] = "perro";
    while(!feof(archivo)){
        fgets(extraer_registros[i],100, archivo);
        printf("%s", extraer_registros[i]);
        if(strcmp(extraer_registros[i], palabra) == 0){
        printf("si esta");
       }
       i++;         
    }
    fclose(archivo);
}
```

Comment: si no recuerdo mal, tu palabra perro tiene 100 caracteres?

Comment: no, solo que necesito que el usuario pueda ingresar una palabra y se elimine del archivo la palabra perro es temporal, ahi es donde se va a almacenar lo que digite el usuario.

Comment: pero definiste un array de 100... no tiene 100 caracteres esa palabra?

Comment: No es solo por si el usuario escribe una palabra grande

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No** indicas el formato de tu archivo; me permito suponer que contendrá una palabra por línea. En ese caso, tu `fgets( )`, además de la propia palabra, también coloca en tu *buffer* el caracter de fín-de-líneas `\n`. Y ese es tu problema.

2 posibles opciones:

1. Incluye ese `\n` en tu palabra:

   ```
   char palabra[] = "perro\n";
   ```
2. No busques una coincidencia exacta; comprueba solo si la cadena leída contiene la palabra al principio:

   ```
   char palabra[] = "perro";
   ...
   if( strstr( extraer_registros[i], palabra ) == extraer_registros[i] )
   ```